# The method OpenFileOutput() is undefined !

Tags: android, local-storage

firstly, I coded some methods in Main Activity, But I decided they should be a class.

this is my code... openFileOutput and openFileInput are undefined. Any idea?? maybe it should be service or activity...??

```
    package spexco.hus.system;

    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Date;
    import spexco.hus.cepvizyon.CepVizyon;
    import android.content.Context;

    public class LicenseIDB {
    private String PHONECODEFILE = "CepVizyonCode";
    private static String PhoneCode = null;

    public LicenseIDB() {
    if (readLocal(PHONECODEFILE, 8) == null)
        createSystemCode();
}

public static long getDate() {
    Date currentTime = new Date();
    return currentTime.getTime();
}

public void createSystemCode() {
    long date = getDate();
    String str = Integer.toHexString(Integer.MAX_VALUE - (int) date);
    for (int i = str.length(); i < 8; i++) {
        str += "" + i;
    }
    PhoneCode = str.substring(0, 8);
    saveLocal(PhoneCode, PHONECODEFILE);

}

public static String getPhoneCode() {

    return PhoneCode;
}

public void saveLocal(String fileString, String Adress) {

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(Adress, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(fileString.getBytes());
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String readLocal(String Adress, int lenght) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[lenght];
    String str = new String();
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(Adress);
        fis.read(buffer);
        fis.close();
        str = new String(buffer);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return str;
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android what is wrong with openFileOutput?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625837/android-what-is-wrong-with-openfileoutput)

Comment: @MichaelGaskill yes, it is possible. But these questions are 6 years old..:) i think, i opened question after I researched a lot. But I don't remember, just thinking..:)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Those are methods defined on the `Context` class, not methods defined in your class. When your code was part of an [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), it could use a convenience method [openFileInput()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput%28java.lang.String%29) in its `Activity` base class to access the underlying [Context.getApplicationContext().openFileInput()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput%28java.lang.String%29) (and similarly for `openFileOutput()`).

Now you'll have to replace those with the direct calls to the underlying [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) methods.

Answer (score 13):

Replace

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(Adress, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

with below line

```
FileOutputStream fos = getApplicationContext().openFileOutput(filename, getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
```

If used inside Fragment

```
FileOutputStream fos =getActivity().openFileOutput(filename, getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: I am doing `getContext().openFileOutput(filename,Context.MODE_PRIVATE)` inside a fragment ,and it still works....My question is what is the difference between `getContext()` and `getActivity()` .

Comment: I'm in a fragment and 'getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE' did not work for me. I just used Context.MODE_PRIVATE