# read file from another activity

Tags: android, fileinputstream

I want to read a text file that i had write in another activity using OutputStreamWriter.
this is my readFromFile method in Sale.java:

```
private int readFromFile(String request) {

        int res = 0;
        try {
            //InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("dalassnums.txt");
            File file=new File("dalassnums.txt");
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

            if ( inputStream != null ) {
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String receiveString = "";

                while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                    String s=bufferedReader.readLine();
                    if(receiveString==request)  {
                        res=Integer.valueOf(s);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                inputStream.close();

            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
            res=0;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            //Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());

        }

        return res;



    }
```

And this is writeToFile method in MainActivity.java:

```
private void writeToFile2(String numchar) {
    try {
        //File file=new File("dalassnums.txt");
        //OutputStream outputStream=new FileOutputStream(file);
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter;
        if(numchar=="1") outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("dalassnums.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        else  outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("dalassnums.txt", Context.MODE_APPEND));
        for(int k=0; k<imageNums.size();k+=2){
        outputStreamWriter.append(imageNums.get(k));
        outputStreamWriter.append("\n");
        outputStreamWriter.append(imageNums.get(k+1));
        outputStreamWriter.append("\n");
        }
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    } 
}
```

When performing readFromFile, it returns 0 that means file not found;
I read about passing context but i don't know what context to pass; And wondering if there is any other way than passing context.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use : `openFileInput` in `readFromFile`, look here for example:

[openFileInput() and/or openFileOutput() i/o streams silently failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18266223/openfileinput-and-or-openfileoutput-i-o-streams-silently-failing)

Another problem is that this is invalid:

```
if(numchar=="1")
```

you should

```
if(numchar.equals("1"))
```

otherwise you compare reference values instead content of string

Comment: What problem with Context you had? Use either your Activity as Context, ie. pass `this` from inside your Activity, or use getApplicationContext. openFileInput / openFileOutput sets correct paths to your file, so they should be used together.

Comment: I used getApplicationContext; Nothing changed, still returning 0 :/

Comment: Oh, Thanks, I was looking for this bug.
Sorry if i'm bothering you... Do you have any other idea about why i can't read that file?

Comment: By using `FileInputStream` instead of `InputStream` and changing  `if(receiveString==request)` to `if(receiveString.equals(request))` problem solved. Thank you