# Reading and writing to files in internal storage on Android

Tags: android, file, storage, internal

I'm learning to write and read files from the internal storage on Android. I have this code:

```
String fileName = "MyFile";
String content = "hello world";

FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
try {
outputStream = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
outputStream.write(content.getBytes());
    outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Where is my file stored and how to read it?

Comment: you should write your openFileOutput function.

Comment: Please refer this link , it may help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53130404/7200297

Comment: Please refer the beneath link, it may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53130404/7200297

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing/Reading Files to/from Android phone's internal memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9306155/608639)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The File should be saved under /data/data/Android/urpackagename/ folder.

To read

```
 FileInputStream in = openFileInput("filename.txt");
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(in);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
}
```

For More Detail with same piece of code [Write and Read openFile...() api](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18269276/3782085)

Answer (score 0):

Since you made it private, with the use of openFileOutput() it's private to your app alone and should be within it's directory "/data/data/" 
Read:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/47924/where-android-apps-store-data