# How to write to a file on Android?

Tags: java, android, file, file-io

For the past 3 hours I've been trying to write to a file in Andoid.

This is my latest attempt:

```
try {
    String text="alo";
    FileOutputStream fos=openFileOutput("gameProg.txt",Context.MODE_APPEND);
    fos.write(text.getBytes());
    fos.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have also tried some FileWriter method that only leads to the read-only file system error. Apart from this FileOutputStream attempt, I have deleted several others which did not have an impact on the file.
Is there any way that I could write to this file (without rooting my phone)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android what is wrong with openFileOutput?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625837/android-what-is-wrong-with-openfileoutput)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't solve my issue